# VueJs - Element UI: How to get change el-date-picker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, element-ui

I have a case with Element UI 2.4.3 (actually for now i use 2.4.1).

When i use el-date-picker @change: in previous version it runs fine, but when Element UI has an update is el-date-picker :@change not working.

can you help me?

here my code

```
<el-date-picker v-model="form.birthdayName" type="date"  @change="dateChangebirthday"  format="dd-MM-yyyy" value-format="yyyy-MM-dd"  placeholder="Pick a day">
</el-date-picker>
```

here my fiddle (Element UI: 2.3.9) = https://jsfiddle.net/dede402/v86npjsg/3/

here my fiddle (Element UI: 2.4.3) = https://jsfiddle.net/dede402/875pe9zo/3/

Comment: It looks like an issue with `value-format`. Maybe it's worth raising an issue on GitHub?  There's an error in the console - `TypeError: e.getHours is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

```
@change="dateChangebirthday($event)"

new Vue({ ...
methods: {
  dateChangebirthday(event){
  console.log(event);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under your contribution to add information about how your suggestion answers the question.